# recipient_delimiter in MS-Exchange

Tags: exchange

Most UNIX mail server support recipient delimiters behind a plus sign in email addresses.

```
user+everything@my-exchange.com
```

In the above example "everything" could be any string, and the mail should get into the mail box of the user "user".

In postfix it is called recipient_delimiter:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

Is this possible with Exchange 2010?

Usecase1:
The user can use different email addresses. He can use user+fooshop@my-exchange.com for the communication with "fooshop". If he gets spam mail to this address later, he knows that fooshop has given his address to someone else.

Usecase2: We run a ticket system ( http://tbz-pariv.de/software/modwork/ ) and want to add send scans via email to the system. The network scanner can only modify the to-address and we want to insert the ticket type like this import+tt=foo@my-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Nope - Exchange 2010 doesn't support this out of the box. 
It probably wouldn't be too hard to add this as a transport agent with some programming.

Though, what do you use this for actually? The postfix documentation is rather vague and it seems to mean that postfix would try the addresses "user+everything", "user" and "everything". So is this just a shorthand for those three addresses and you use it instead of trying all three when sending an email into that org? Or does something else happen with that "everything" string? Where does it go?

Comment: Where is goes depends on the client. For example, Gmail takes anything after the + and tags the email with that. So if you use an email address like claus+serverfault@gmail.com then any email sent to that address will automatically get a serverfault tag. Use a different address for each site you sign up with and you can tell who is sharing your email address.